# Get scale el jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Can you please advise me how I can take the scale value of an element using jquery?

```js
var scale = $("div").css("scale");
console.log(scale);
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  scale: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>TEST</div>
```

Comment: the correct property name for scale in CSS is `transform`, `var scale = $("div").css("transform");` and in your css `transform: scale(0.5);`

Comment: @ChrisG [scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scale) is also valid since somewhat recently

Comment: @ChrisG most transforms are now [first-class rules](https://web.dev/articles/css-individual-transform-properties) in CSS3.

Comment: You should ask yourself, _if I need access to modern web APIs, should I really be using jQuery?_ If you are using jQuery for legacy browsers, you probably won't be able to take advantage of cutting-edge CSS properties anyways.

Comment: Provided snippet appears to do exactly what you are asking for - what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine in any browser that is running the following (minimum) versions:

| Chrome | Edge | Firefox | Safari |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 104 | 104 | 72 | 14.1 |

I changed the ruleset for `div` to `.test` and gave your `div` the `test` class. It was causing the console to be rendered very small.

```js
var scale = $("div").css("scale");

console.log(scale); // "0.5"
```

```css
.test {
  scale: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">TEST</div>
```

For more information on these rules, checkout this *web.dev* article:

> ["Finer grained control over CSS transforms with individual transform properties"](https://web.dev/articles/css-individual-transform-properties)